# Как скомпилировать async\await с помощью babel?

Tags: javascript

Сам уже отчаялся и чтобы не писать тонну чувств которые я испытал сегодня, просто попрошу дать мне конфиг проекта который может **скомпилировать** **async\await** с помощью только **babel**, без **webpack**.

То есть если взять что-то из **es6** и скомпилировать **babel**, то это свободно можно открывать в любом браузере. Но я не могу сделать тоже самое для **async\await**. а те скудные ошибки которые выводятся приводят меня на ответы в которых говорят что нужно ТОЛЬКО рантайм компилятор подключать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я использую better-babel-cli для запуска babel и передачи параметров в плагины из консоли (хотя зесь в этом нет необходимости, просто лень делать babelrc).

скомпилировать можно так:

```
babel  --async-to-generator --transform-regenerator -- async.js > babel_async.js
```

async.js:

```
var bar = function(){
    return new Promise( function( good, bad ){
        setTimeout( good, 1000, ' good' );
    } );
}
async function foo() {
    console.log( 'checking async life' );
    var res = await bar();
    console.log( 'async life is ' + res )
}

foo();
```

Результат:

```
let foo = (() => {
    var ref = _asyncToGenerator(regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
        var res;
        return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function _callee$(_context) {
            while (1){
                switch (_context.prev = _context.next) {
                case 0:
                    console.log('checking async life');
                    _context.next = 3;
                    return bar();

                case 3:
                    res = _context.sent;

                    console.log('async life is ' + res);

                case 5:
                case 'end':
                    return _context.stop();
                }
            }
        }, _callee, this);
    }));

    return function foo() {
        return ref.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();

function _asyncToGenerator(fn) { return function () { var gen = fn.apply(this, arguments); return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) { function step(key, arg) { try { var info = gen[key](arg); var value = info.value; } catch (error) { reject(error); return; } if (info.done) { resolve(value); } else { return Promise.resolve(value).then(function (value) { return step("next", value); }, function (err) { return step("throw", err); }); } } return step("next"); }); }; }

var bar = function () {
    return new Promise(function (good, bad) {
        console.log('new promise');
        setTimeout(good, 1000, ' good');
    });
```

};

--async-to-generator [плагин](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-async-to-generator/) для преобразования async/await в es6 генераторы

--transform-generator - плагин для преобразования es6 генераторов (часть es2015) в es5 (для работы es5 трансформированного кода требудется грузить дополнительную библиотеку), [можно взять тут](https://github.com/facebook/regenerator/blob/master/packages/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js))

Если в ie запускаться не нужно то можно без второга плагина.

Изменение:

Добавил ссылку на async плагин.

Кстати async/await это не es6 код, даже не es7 (await упоминается только как зарезервированное слово).